# How to set uniform font size both in the table and the paragraph

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

When I resize the table, using `\resizebox` or any other thing, the font size gets reduced. How do I set, a uniform font size for the whole document, I need at least 12pt (the minimum requirement).

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,borde=10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.25\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.15\linewidth}}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{}%
%
\renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
%  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}% ORIGINAL
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}% NEW
  %\hfil% ORIGINAL
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
%    \centering% ORIGINAL
    \raggedright% NEW
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title)
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\       %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
  \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      }}%
      \hfill
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \raggedleft%    %% optional
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\name{SUBHAM}{SONI}
%\address{No.8, I-Floor, I-Cross, Suriya Gandhi Nagar(North), Muthialpet}{Puducherry $-$ 605003}{India}
%\phone[mobile]{+91~8124~410~721}
%\phone[fixed]{+91~0413~22~11~380}
%\email{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}
%\social[github]{jdoe}
%\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
A challenging role in a dynamic organisation, which would serve as a platform for being
resourceful, innovative and flexible, where good technical and soft skills can enhance the
company's welfare and offer professional growth.
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\centering
%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}\hline
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Years of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \hline
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & $8.554^\star$ \\     \hline
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & 92\% \\   \hline
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & 90\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{${}^\star$ Cumulative grade point average up to $5^{th}$ semester}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should not put it in a table then, but a list rather... is that an option?

Comment: 99% its a no.... @Werner

Comment: Your table doesn't fit, so the only thing you can do is to resize it (make it smaller). To make the text match, you then actually have to increase the font size of the table so that in shrinking it matches the outer text, but that doesn't look good. One thing you can attempt is to use a `c` column for the first and last. But you're still short of space horizontally...

Comment: That's why I'd never (or hardly ever) suggest resizing text units such as tables. Choose a font that works such as `\small` and use it consistently.

Comment: You are wasting loads of space for the first column, why are you setting that in a fixed width column that is 1/4 of the text width, if you used `c` it would be more reasonable (same for the last column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `tabulary`. Define a new column like

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

and choose specify appropriate column widths for each column:

```
\begin{tabular}{|C{\dimexpr0.06\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 C{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 C{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}\hline
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,borde=10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{}%
%
\renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
%  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}% ORIGINAL
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}% NEW
  %\hfil% ORIGINAL
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
%    \centering% ORIGINAL
    \raggedright% NEW
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title)
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\       %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
  \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      }}%
      \hfill
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \raggedleft%    %% optional
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\name{SUBHAM}{SONI}
%\address{No.8, I-Floor, I-Cross, Suriya Gandhi Nagar(North), Muthialpet}{Puducherry $-$ 605003}{India}
%\phone[mobile]{+91~8124~410~721}
%\phone[fixed]{+91~0413~22~11~380}
%\email{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}
%\social[github]{jdoe}
%\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
A challenging role in a dynamic organisation, which would serve as a platform for being
resourceful, innovative and flexible, where good technical and soft skills can enhance the
company's welfare and offer professional growth.
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\centering
%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering

     \begin{tabular}{|C{\dimexpr0.06\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      C{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                      C{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}\hline
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Years of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \hline
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & $8.554^\star$ \\     \hline
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & 92\% \\   \hline
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & 90\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{${}^\star$ Cumulative grade point average up to $5^{th}$ semester}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an option using `booktabs` and no vertical lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,borde=10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{}%
%
\renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
%  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}% ORIGINAL
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}% NEW
  %\hfil% ORIGINAL
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
%    \centering% ORIGINAL
    \raggedright% NEW
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title)
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\       %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
  \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      }}%
      \hfill
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \raggedleft%    %% optional
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\name{SUBHAM}{SONI}
%\address{No.8, I-Floor, I-Cross, Suriya Gandhi Nagar(North), Muthialpet}{Puducherry $-$ 605003}{India}
%\phone[mobile]{+91~8124~410~721}
%\phone[fixed]{+91~0413~22~11~380}
%\email{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}
%\social[github]{jdoe}
%\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
A challenging role in a dynamic organisation, which would serve as a platform for being
resourceful, innovative and flexible, where good technical and soft skills can enhance the
company's welfare and offer professional growth.
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\centering
%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
   \tabcolsep=3pt
     \begin{tabular}{C{\dimexpr0.06\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}\toprule
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Years of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \midrule
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & $8.554^\star$ \\     
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & 92\% \\   
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & 90\% \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{${}^\star$ Cumulative grade point average up to $5^{th}$ semester}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Additional notes**

1. Instead of `$5^{th}$`, use `5\textsuperscript{th}`.
2. `Years of passing` should be `Year of passing`
3. Instead of using `$8.554^\star$` and `${}^\star$` (inside `tablenotes`) combo, you can use `8.554\tnote{*}` and inside `tablenotes`, `\item [*] \textbf{Cumulative .....`. The package `threeparttable` provides `\tnote` macro.

With these additional notes incorporated, you get:

[image]

Comment: Will it be nice If I add a `\hline' after every entry???

Comment: @subhamsoni I wouldn't add. But it is only subjective.

Comment: How do I get these styled numbers....?

Comment: @subhamsoni They come with `libertine`. Name is `old-style figures.

Comment: I have given `\usepackage{libertine}` but I didnt get it :(

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,borde=10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{}%
%
\renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
%  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}% ORIGINAL
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}% NEW
  %\hfil% ORIGINAL
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
%    \centering% ORIGINAL
    \raggedright% NEW
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title)
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\       %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
  \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\     %%% <--- HK here
      }}%
      \hfill
    \parbox[t]{0.45\maketitlewidth}{%
    \raggedleft%    %% optional
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\           %% <--- HK here
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}           %% <--- HK here
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\name{SUBHAM}{SONI}
%\address{No.8, I-Floor, I-Cross, Suriya Gandhi Nagar(North), Muthialpet}{Puducherry $-$ 605003}{India}
%\phone[mobile]{+91~8124~410~721}
%\phone[fixed]{+91~0413~22~11~380}
%\email{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}
%\social[github]{jdoe}
%\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
A challenging role in a dynamic organisation, which would serve as a platform for being
resourceful, innovative and flexible, where good technical and soft skills can enhance the
company's welfare and offer professional growth.
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\centering
%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering

     \begin{tabulary}{\columnwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}\hline
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Years of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \hline
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & $8.554^\star$ \\     \hline
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & 92\% \\   \hline
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & 90\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{${}^\star$ Cumulative grade point average up to $5^{th}$ semester}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```